# Backup locked huawei p9 before hard reset

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow

Is it possible to backup a locked Huawei p9 phone before hard reset; even with USB Debugging off?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible to backup all your data via USB with 'USB Debugging **off**'.

But it may be possible, if you make a backup using **`TWRP`** (android app.) with root access in mobile's external card.

Comment: Thank you guys for responding. @Gerry, quick question, won't backing up using TWRP delete all my data on the internal memory?

Comment: swap(delete) memory and take backup and many more options are there present.